# Is there a way to auto-center the camera behind Sora?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

This is something that drives me crazy on the best of days, but working on the barrel breaking bit is really making it an issue.

Is there a button I can press that automatically centers the camera behind Sora? Is there somewhere I need to enable an option or something? Because this is getting ridiculous!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click R2 and L2 at the same time and it will center the camera behind Sora.

Comment: This is the best news I have heard all day.